# Eigenvectors of $\begin{pmatrix}2&-2\\ -4&-2\end{pmatrix}$ - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Eigenvalues are $2\sqrt{3}$ and $-2\sqrt{3}$, I'll calculate the eigenvector for $2\sqrt{3}$ here

We've got:

$\begin{pmatrix}2-2\sqrt{3}&-2\\ -4&-2-2\sqrt{3}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\ y_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$

I multiply the first row by negative 1, I get:

$\begin{pmatrix}-2+2\sqrt{3}&2\\ -4&-2-2\sqrt{3}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\ y_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$

I add the first and second row together, I get:

$\left(-6+2\sqrt{3}\right)y_1-2\sqrt{3}y_2=0$

So the solution would be

$\left(-\sqrt{3}+1\right)y_1=y_2$

The eigenvector is $\begin{pmatrix}y\\ \left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)y\end{pmatrix}$

But that's apparently wrong [according to this calculator](https://matrixcalc.org/en/vectors.html#eigenvectors%28%7B%7B2,-2%7D,%7B-4,-2%7D%7D%29)

What's wrong here?

Comment: This is the same eigenvector. Consider using $y=x_2/(1-\sqrt{3})$ and then$$\frac1{1-\sqrt{3}}=-\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}2$$

Comment: Right, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You did nothing wrong. What you got were that the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $2\sqrt3$ are those of the form $\left(1,1-\sqrt3\right)^Ty$, with $y\ne0$. That calculator got the vectors of the form $\left(-\frac{\sqrt3+1}2,1\right)^Ty$ with $y\ne0$. But$$\left(-\frac{\sqrt3+1}2\right)\begin{pmatrix}1\\1-\sqrt3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{\sqrt3+1}2\\1\end{pmatrix}.$$So, it's the same answer.

Comment: Could I ask you another question (because I can only post threads every 40 minutes here)? I know that the second eigenvector is equal to $\begin{pmatrix}z\\ \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)z\end{pmatrix}$, if $\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}y\\ \:\left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)y\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}z\\ \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)z\end{pmatrix}$ then would y=0 and z=0?

Comment: Yes. Eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are always linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear that your answer disagrees with the source you cite.
\begin{align}
& \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 1- \sqrt 3 \end{array} \right] = \frac 1 {1+\sqrt3} \left[ \begin{array}{c} (1+\sqrt3\,)\cdot1 \\[4pt] (1+\sqrt3\,) (1- \sqrt 3\,) \end{array} \right] \\[15pt]
= {} & \frac 1 {1+\sqrt3} \left[\begin{array}{c} 1+ \sqrt 3 \\[4pt] -2 \end{array} \right] = \frac {-2} {1+\sqrt3} \left[\begin{array}{c} (-1- \sqrt 3\,)/2 \\[4pt] 1 \end{array} \right]
\end{align}

Comment: Could I ask you another question (because I can only post threads every 40 minutes here)? I know that the second eigenvector is equal to $\begin{pmatrix}z\\ \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)z\end{pmatrix}$, if $\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}y\\ \:\left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)y\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}z\\ \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)z\end{pmatrix}$ then would y=0 and z=0?

Comment: Yes. It is clear that $y=0=z$ is a solution, and the question is whether it's the ONLY solution. And it is, because the two vectors are linearly independent.